# How to install neo4j on Nitrous.IO?

Tags: neo4j, nitrousio

Here's what I've attempted via the Nitrous.IO Console:

- wget http://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-community-1.9.4-unix.tar.gz
- tar xvfz neo4j-community-1.9.4-unix.tar.gz
- mv neo4j-community-1.9.4 neo4j
- neo4j/bin/neo4j start

Here is what it says:

```
WARNING: Max 512 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.                                                                          
neo4j/bin/neo4j: line 143: lsof: command not found                                                                                                                 
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/log
ging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled                                             
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user                                                                                                                 
process [1470]... waiting for server to be ready.neo4j/bin/neo4j: line 143: lsof: command not found                                                                
.neo4j/bin/neo4j: line 143: lsof: command not found                                                                                                                
.neo4j/bin/neo4j: line 143: lsof: command not found
```

Do I need to install lsof on my box?  Are we able to do so ourselves on Nitrous.IO?

Comment: What Linux version are you running there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nitrous box does not include lsof by default, and since you don;t have root access you will want to download and install lsof into your home directory.

Once installed, you will want to add it to your PATH. You can download lsof here http://freshmeat.net/projects/lsof/ .